# How does a potentiometer work?

Tags: current, resistance, voltage

A lot of places where I've read explanations about [potentiometers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) either go into so much detail or they're so superficial that I don't understand the actual concept behind it. How would you easily explain to me what a potentiometer is and how it works?

Comment: Do you have a potentiometer (i.e. physical component) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: Get one (preferably an [old-fashioned one like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Potentiometer.jpg)).  Also get a multimeter.  If you play with it for 30 minutes and make some measurements, it will be clear what it does.  It's also advisable that you take it apart and figure out the inner workings.

Comment: Actually, the thing is...I have an exam tomorrow and I don't really understand how potentiometers work so that is why I'm asking here. I don't think I would be able to get one of those before my exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed-resistor potential divider reduces an input voltage to a lower value at the output: -

[image]

If you imagine that \$R_{top}\$ and \$R_{bottom}\$ are combined into one resistor then the wiper position is where top and bottom resistors meet mathematically ; the resistance above the wiper (\$R_{top}\$) is exactly as it was with two separate resistors and the the resistance below the wiper (\$R_{bottom}\$ is also the same.

So, with a potentiometer you vary the tap-point and this means your output voltage can be varied between 0V and Vin.

Comment: So basically, there is a contact which we can move in order to change the output voltage. If we place that contact right in the middle of the wire in a potentiometer, can the output voltage ever be less than half the total input voltage? If so, how?

Comment: Yes to first question and yes to the 2nd because if there is external loads on the pot's output it will be less than half.

Comment: I don't understand that. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Regarding my question, could you answer this based on Q6 part(d) from: http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Physics%20%289702%29/9702_s10_qp_22.pdf

Comment: If the wiper is connected to a circuit that acts as a low value resistor, this low value resistor shunts \$R_{bottom}\$ and reduces the output voltage. Regards Q6(d) - the ammeter is a low value resistance and it shunts the resistance of the wire below the wiper and reduces the reading.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple experiment you can do:

Find a pencil with a soft lead (2B or something). Make a dark, thick rectangle on a piece of paper about 5cm x 5mm or so (a long strip). Using a multimeter set to measure resistance, put one test lead at the very edge of the rectangle you drew, and measure different points along the strip using the other test lead. You should read lower resistances as the two leads are closer together.

A potentiometer uses a similar strip of resistive material (carbon, for example) to provide varying amounts of resistance, based on the distance between two connections to the material.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was originally intended for the physics website, but seeing as I was almost done my answer I'll post it here:

When you adjust the knob on a (analog) potentiometer you change the amount of resistance between W and A and W and B. (W stands for Wiper here).Let's say we apply 5 Volts  between A and B (B being the ground), and attach some other circuit to W. By turning W clockwise we decrease the voltage supplied to W because we have increased the resistance between A and W. If we align W with B, W is now at 0 volts because B is the ground.
We can calculate  $$V_W=V_A-R_{AW}I$$

[image: Analog Potentiometer]

Answer (score 0):

This question comes from over in Physics. I suspect the OP is asking about the measuring device called a Potentiometer that was used extensively until the VTVM was developed.

In Juliens's diagram, consider a reference voltage is connected between A and B. Connect a sensitive galvanometer between W and the voltage to be measured. Adjust the variable resistor until the galvanometer reads zero. Now the Vout is equal to the the voltage under test and there is no current flow, so there is no load on the test point or the variable resistor. Now the Vout can be measured with a meter that has  lower impedance or the variable resistor can be calibrated so the dial or slide position reads in appropriate units. (There are variations on this that eliminate some error sources).

If you ever wondered how they made those great accurate measurements in the 1800's like chemical half-cell potentials and thermopile voltages and the work functions of metals with light shining on them, this was it, along with the ballistic galvanometer and electroplating to measure charge and current.